# VS2010 Opening Database Project Script Throw "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I added a SQl 2008 Database project to my application. Then I created a new table script. When the script tab opens, VS hangs. I then get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Anyone have any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you try to open that script with "Open with..."? Does it work?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen when SQL is installed after VS has been installed.

quoted from post by Andre Davis (answer #6) [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/27ef7c94-4410-4925-ab22-3fec475b1885) :

> To fix the issue of not being able to load the RadLangSvc.Package here is what you need to do:
>
> 1. Load up your ISO or DVD VS2010 Installer in an explorer window
> 2. Go to the WCU foldler
> 3. Go to the DAC folder
> 4. Install MSI's
>
>    - i. DACFramework_enu.msi
>    - ii. DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
>    - iii. TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

Answer (score 0):

I have had installed VS2010 Ultimate with SP1 and SSMS 2012 and was experiencing the same problem - 'Object reference ..' and a hang. I have successfully solved the problem with a [full VS uninstall](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) and removal of SP1. Note that afterthat SSMS started working out of the box.